# Trigger error : syntax error when i create my trigger

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

i am trying to create a trigger in my databse, i want to check if a user tries topurchase the same game more than once, if he does this trigger will occur :

```
CREATE TRIGGER purchase_product
BEFORE INSERT
ON purchases FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE i
set @i = (SELECT count(*) FROM purchases where new.product_id =
purchases.product_id and new.num_id_person = purchases.num_id_person)
if (i > 0) then SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Game already purchased'
end if 
END
```

but i get the error in my syntax, im new to this any help please ?

this is the error i get :

```
SQL query: Copy Documentation


CREATE TRIGGER purchase_product
BEFORE INSERT
ON purchases FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE i
set @i = (SELECT count(*) FROM purchases where new.product_id =
purchases.product_id and new.num_id_person = purchases.num_id_person)
if (i > 0) then SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Game already purchased'
end if 
END
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 
'@i = (SELECT count(*) FROM purchases where new.product_id =
purchases.produc...' at line 6
```

Comment: Why don't you include the error text in the question?

Comment: Every statement needs to be terminated and delimiters set